# Intercepting application HTTP/HTTPS traffic with a proxy

Tags: networking, https, proxy, vpn, intercept

As part of my job,
I need to intercept the communication between a native windows application to a web server. 
My connection to the environment is through an SSL-VPN.
The application (.exe) is installed on my PC and is communicating in HTTPS with the web server over port 1912. 
Usually I use Burp proxy in order to intercept the communication between a browser and a server (configuring the proxy through the browser config). Yet,
In this implementation (native windows application) I cannot figure out how to route the traffic to a proxy.

Is there any specific proxy or configuration which I can use in order to that and use Burp (because it is a web proxy.. I need to mess with HTTP requests)?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to understand is whether this native application is programmed to use proxy. If it can use proxy, it could obtain proxy information from the Windows system or you might need to configure just for the application inside the application.

Other possibility it to use the default gateway, and redirect requests with HTTP response 3XX to your proxy. It might work depending on your native application. The default gateway might just act as a proxy.

I suppose here you are not talking about reverse proxy and forward proxy caching (https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/4.2.x/admin/reverse-proxy-http-redirects.en.html)

Comment: Hi @rodolk, thanks for you answer. The application does not have any network config which can be set to proxy. Moreover, I wish to not only intercept/log responses, but also requests. Is there anyway that I could set this up using a specific proxy/software/windows configuration..?

Comment: @JinKazama, try and see if it uses the system proxy. If not try the other possibility I mentioned.